# Common element in each pairwise intersecting subfamily of real numbered intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the family of closed intervals of real numbers, and suppose that we have a subfamily of $n$ intervals $ \mathbb{I}=\{ I_1, I_2, \ldots I_n \}$ such that each pairwise intersection of its elements is nonempty. That is, $\forall i,j \in [n]$, we have $I_i \cap I_j = [a_{i,j}, b_{i,j}]\neq \emptyset$.

The Helly Property states that the intervals in the subfamily must all contain a common element.

Can we say that the common element is obtained by writing down the result of each pairwise intersection $ \{ [a_{1,2}, b_{1,2}], [a_{1,3}, b_{1,3}], \ldots,[a_{n,n-1}, b_{n,n-1}] \} $ and simply taking the largest $a$ and smallest $b$ to form a new interval $[a,b]$? Would such an interval be contained in all of the intervals in the subfamily $\mathbb{I}$?

I think it's true, but I do not know how to start the proof. Also, please excuse my rather messy explanation. I am still learning!